# What's the difference between a Docker Ubuntu container and an LxD Ubuntu container?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, container, lxc

I've read that Docker is an *application* container mainly used to package dependencies along with the application in question.

Whereas, LxD is a *system* (or, *infrastructure*) container that is almost  like a lightweight VM instance, with ability to run not only Docker but also LxD inside of it, in addition to other applications.

**Question:** But what about a Docker container for [Ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/), that is a full-fledged OS? How would it compare to a Ubuntu LxD container?

Comment: Take a look: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254956/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-lxd-and-lxc

Comment: @duDE That still doesn't answer my question, namely: If I'm running a Docker-container launched from a whole, blessed Ubuntu image (and NOT a single app container for Httpd, Nodejs, etc), then in **what all** ways is it different from an LxD container for Ubuntu? In this Docker Ubuntu container, I can go on installing as many apps as I want (including Docker itself and LxD), just as I could in an LxD container.

Comment: I think @duDE wanted to point you to this answer (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254977). it should answer your question. brief summary: Docker hosts application containers (the app and its identity), LXD hosts machine containers (like a Linux virtual machine).

Comment: Guys, I understand what LxC is! What I don't understand, still, is: If my Docker container is a **whole** Ubuntu OS container (instead of merely an application container like httpd, node, mysqld etc), then how is it any different from an LxD OS container?

Comment: IMHO the Docker is a kind of manager over differnet LxC. "Docker acts as a portable container engine, packaging the application and all its dependencies in a virtual container that can run on any Linux server." - from https://www.upguard.com/articles/docker-vs-lxc