# Difference between an LXD Ubuntu container, and a Docker container with an Ubuntu image?

Tags: virtualization, container, lxc

I think this question was already asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1143632), and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254956) was referenced, but it doesn't really answer. So I'll try to ask more in detail.

Let's say I have an LXD container running an instance of Ubuntu, and another docker container with an Ubuntu image.

What is the difference between these two? Any examples of what can I do in one, that I can't do in the other? Does one of them use more memory/cpu?

Comment: the [second-highest answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254982) on that unix.stackex link is probably a better reference for you, particularly [the infographic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5Neb.png).  the answer to your question would be an explicit LXD comparison on the infographic.

Comment: I looked at the infographic. "Containers with a fully functional OS" vs "designed to support a single application". Would the Ubuntu image in docker be considered a single application, even though I can use apt-get to download packages? "Instances are ephemeral" My docker containers can store files in their home directory even after I stop the containers (home directory isn't host system mounted directory). "FS Neutral" vs "Read-only layers" I don't really understand what this means. Is it just some implementation difference? Can I notice this difference from inside the container?